# VBA print all COM addins

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I'm trying to print all com addins in my excel application through VBA but there is something wrong with the code below. The error seems to be on the For each line...any thoughts much appreciated

```
Sub showAddins()
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim myAddin As Excel.AddIn

    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    For Each myAddin In excelApp.COMAddIns

        Debug.Print myAddin.Name

    Next myAddin

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you have COM-AddIns installed? If there are no AddIns, the `COMAddIns` throws an error rather than jump over the loop. 

Furthermore, I don't think you need a new `Excel.Application`-object, simply using `Appliation` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes I have some that are 'ticked' and one that is not. Ultimatelly what Im trying to achieve is to 'tick' all COM Addins through VBA...any further thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addins do not load when Excel is opened using automation, so there will be none loaded in the new instance you create in your code.

Just use the existing Application reference in your already-open Excel instance:

```
Sub showAddins()

    Dim myAddin 'as variant

    For Each myAddin In Application.COMAddIns

        Debug.Print myAddin.Description '<< not Name

    Next myAddin

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - still getting the same error message though. Its like Application.COMAddIns is causing the trouble. If I change COMAddins to AddIns only the code works fine. I want to print the list of COM Addins though - under Excel Options -> Add-Ins -> Manage -> COM Addins

Comment: See my updates - I hadn't tested, so a couple of issues there, for example `Name` is not a property on the add-in.

Comment: Thanks this prints is the description. I'd like to check if the addin is loaded/installed, would you be able to help with that too? I tried If myAddin.Installed Then ... but that gave me error